# Unable to translate a lot of sentences on revisions page if there was a redaction

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, revision-redaction

All following strings are not in translation data base:

> Another revision of this post has previously been redacted (“{description}”). That redaction can be automatically applied to this revision as well.

> The previous redaction performed the following change:

> The suggested automatic redaction would make the following change to this revision:

> After the automatic redaction, this revision would appear in the revision list as follows:

> note: Please check carefully that the suggestion makes sense before applying it.

> warning: There are overlapping edits between the redaction and this revision. Check … very very carefully.

> Yet another note: The automatic suggestion currently only handles the post body. If you need to redact title or tags, you have to do that part manually.

That's how it look on the page:

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]